# Custom Filters matching questions from any of the named tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-filters

Currently saved *custom* filters (in the right panel) composed with a set of tags are getting applied on strict `AND` rule (all or nothing).

A more expected and preferred behavior of such filter is extracting questions on **`ANY`** rule and ordered by "post date" (*"Newest"*).

With "*all or nothing"* rule it's filtering quite an old questions (even if *"Sorted by"* param is set to *"Newest"*) while filtering on separate tag gives a recent questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom filters work just like search does: all tags must match for questions to appear in the list. *Unless* you tell it to use the `or` operator explicitly.

Enter `tagname or tagname or tagname or tagname` in the filter and it’ll limit the results to questions matching *any* of the selected tags. And the results are *live*, new posts matching the criteria can be loaded as they are posted.

This works even on a mobile browser; this is taken from my personal filter (which is really quite long and I ran out of patience circling all the `or` keywords):

[image]

Comment: That's really good to know, thanks. Man, I see `python-2.4` tag in your filter, can't believe anybody is still using it :)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: I monitor all things Python. :-) Sometimes someone is stuck with old software versions, they still deserve help.